# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id'). AntiScam system

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wrote an anti-scam system but after launching I got an error

**AntiScam.js**

```
onst { Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../Structures/config.json");
const DB = require("../../Structures/Schemas/AntiScamDB");

module.exports = {
name: "messageCreate",
/\*\*
\*
\* @param {Message} message
\*/
async execute(message) {
DB.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) =\> {
if (!data) return;
if(err) throw err;
const array = require(\`../../Structures/Valdiation/ScamLink.json\`);
if (array.some((word) =\> message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
message.delete();
const Ex = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Scam detected")
.setColor(config.Warna)
.setThumbnail(\`${message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}\`)
.setDescription(\`Please don't send any scam messages. Thank you.\`)
.addField(
"User:",
\`\\\`\\\`\\\`${message.author.tag} (${message.author.id})\\\`\\\`\\\`\`
)
.addField("Message Content:", \`\\\`\\\`\\\`${message.content}\\\`\\\`\\\`\`)
.setTimestamp();

        await message.guild.channels.cache.get(data.Channel).send({embeds: \[Ex\]});
      }
    });

},
};
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\Events\Client\AntiScam.js:12
    DB.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\Events\Client\AntiScam.js:12:39)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\Structures\Handlers\Events.js:22:54)
    at Client.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\ekmrr\Desktop\squeak\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Please help!

At the beginning of the construction of the database and json arose, but after writing the command, the bot passed out :(

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I cannot read your code clearly, but I can tell you that `message.guild` you are sending to `DB.findOne` is `null`.

I believe to play it safe with this you can do something like

```
message.hasOwnProperty('guild') &&
message.guild.hasOwnProperty('id') &&
DB.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
...
```

or

```
if (message.guild !== null)
DB.findOne({ Guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
...
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Why did you put a `\` in front of the `>`? It might a bug because I think I heard a bug about that on [meta]

Comment: It is a paste issue I believe, I have no idea. I've edited my answer, thanks for the note. - edit: I copied it from the question code and the code had this :)